# Is this product suitable as a solvent cement for abs pipes?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, drain-waste-vent, welding

I have this at home:
[Glue](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tangit-125-Gr-Sticker-Glue-Special-Henkel-Pipes-PVC-ABS-Wallcovering-Repair-Seal-/163993385693?_trksid=p2349526.m4383.l4275.c10)

and I need to solvent-weld these abs drain piping:

[pipe](https://www.wolseley.co.uk/product/center-cp2%3Aw-waste-pipe-3-m--11-2/) and [elbow](https://www.wolseley.co.uk/product/center-cb2%3Aw-knuckle-bend-90-deg-11-2/)

Can I avoid purchasing solvent cement?
Or would that present some problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the marking on the tube it's rated for both EN14680 (Adhesives for non-pressure thermoplastics piping systems) as well as EN14814 (Adhesives for thermoplastic piping systems for fluids under pressure).
The [product datasheet I found](https://docs.rs-online.com/59b6/0900766b80fd8247.pdf) says:

> Tangit PVC-U is suitable for producing tensile stress resistant
>   connections between pipes (e.g. drinking water and gas pipes) and
>   fittings made of PVC-U* in compliance with the recommendations of the
>   German Plastic Pipe Association.
>   *PVC-U = rigid PVC

**But - on page 2 it says:**

> **The recommended product for pipes made of ABS is Tangit ABS**

My best guess is that it'll probably work sorta-kinda-ok-ish, but I wouldn't use your PVC-U on ABS pipes except as a last resort in a non-demanding application.